# TypeError: global.performance.now is not a function in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Yj5j.png)

Unable to find any solution to this query.

```
TypeError: global.performance.now is not a function
at node_modules/expo/build/logs/LogSerialization.js:156:14 in _captureConsoleStackTrace
at node_modules/expo/build/logs/LogSerialization.js:41:26 in serializeLogDataAsync
- ... 9 more stack frames from framework internals
```

Comment: please share your code for more info

Answer (score 26, accepted):

make change to this file: node_modules/react-native-reanimated/src/reanimated2/core.ts
Line 386, remove this:

```
global.performance = {
 now: global._chronoNow,
```

};

then add this:

```
if(global.performance == null) {
    global.performance = {
      now: global._chronoNow,
    };
  }
```

Comment: it's a temporary solution. please provide a permanent solution.cause of every time it has been changed after node module installation.

Comment: If you don't want to downgrade and want to persist your node_modules patch:


    npx patch-package react-native-reanimated

Comment: use patch-package

Answer (score 4):

This is reanimated issue, fix will be released soon https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/commit/aef72c0875b559eecb7e10abaf00e49186d7ae55, for now, I would advise downgrading it to 2.2.4

Comment: "react-native-reanimated": "^2.3.1"

it is also coming in latest version of reanimated

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the expo application, then try reinstalling the latest expo application or connect the device to the computer and run the `expo start` command, then hit `(a or i)` to automatically install the compatible version on your devices.