# undefined is not an object global.performance.now in expo react native project

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-reanimated

[image: 1]

I'm trying to run the app using the expo start command. It worked fine so far but today it's showing like this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

These are my dependencies

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo-google-fonts/manrope": "^0.2.0",
    "@expo-google-fonts/roboto": "^0.2.2",
    "@expo/react-native-action-sheet": "^3.12.0",
    "@flyerhq/react-native-link-preview": "^1.6.0",
    "@gorhom/bottom-sheet": "4",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "~1.15.0",
    "@react-native-community/clipboard": "^1.5.1",
    "@react-native-community/hooks": "^2.8.1",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "7.1.3",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^14.5.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^14.5.0",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "2.2.1",
    "@react-navigation/core": "^6.1.1",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^6.0.6",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.6",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.2.5",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.1.1",
    "@stomp/stompjs": "^6.1.2",
    "@stripe/stripe-react-native": "0.2.3",
    "expo-linking": "~3.0.0",
    "expo-media-library": "~14.0.0",
    "expo-notifications": "~0.14.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.14.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.2.0",
    "expo-updates": "~0.11.6",
    "expo-web-browser": "~10.1.0",
    "firebase": "^9.6.7",
    "firebase-admin": "^10.0.0",,
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.3",
    "react-native-actionsheet": "^2.4.2",
    "react-native-bottomsheet-reanimated": "^0.1.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.1.0",
    "react-native-hold-menu": "^0.1.1",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.37.2",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^4.7.0",
    "react-native-image-resizer": "^1.4.5",
    "react-native-image-viewing": "^0.2.1",
    "react-native-ionicons": "^4.x",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
    "react-native-link-preview": "^1.4.2",
    "react-native-pager-view": "5.4.9",
    "react-native-parsed-text": "^0.0.22",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^8.1.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "2.4.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.10.1",
    "react-native-sticky-parallax-header": "^0.4.1",
    "react-native-svg": "12.1.1",
    "react-native-svg-charts": "^5.4.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.1.1",
    "react-native-unimodules": "0.12.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.0.0",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.1",
    "react-native-webview": "11.15.0",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.4",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.12.0",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.4.1",
    "sockjs-client": "1.4.0",
    "stompjs": "2.3.3",
    "text-encoding": "^0.7.0",
    "url": "^0.11.0",
    "watchman": "^1.0.0"
  }}
```

I've tried changing the versions of the react-native-reanimated package but still couldn't figure out the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: global.performance.now is not a function in react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70564386/typeerror-global-performance-now-is-not-a-function-in-react-native)

Comment: No, it doesn't provide the perfect solution :(

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem recently myself. I'm not entirely sure why this is happening but you can try to find the root cause by trial and error. For me, I did a global find of all references to `global.performance.now` in the `build` folder and commented out all of them in the code (they were all js files from `node_modules` packages in the `build` folder). Once I tried to reload the app, I would get a more detailed message about a missing reference or undefined variable (since I commented the lines calling on `global.performance.now`). In my case, it ended up being located in the `react-native` package, specifically in the [`createPerformanceLogger.js`](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/main/Libraries/Utilities/createPerformanceLogger.js#L60) file. What was interesting was that I was able to find another file in the package that actually sets up this object [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/main/Libraries/Core/setUpPerformance.js).

So, as a temporary workaround, I added a `require('../Core/setUpPerformance');` statement in the `createPerformanceLogger.js` import statements. This fixed the issue for me. Obviously, this isn't pretty since it requires altering build files. What I did was add a post-build step to do this programmatically after every build in order to avoid doing this manually ([my setup uses `Kotlinjs` as well](https://github.com/tatumalenko/MailrKt), so I added it as a post assemble step in my [`gradle.build.kts`](https://github.com/tatumalenko/MailrKt/blob/main/shared/build.gradle.kts#L51-L64) file). In any case, YMMV but determining the root cause this way will help unblock you in the meantime until finding a more long term solution.

It's worth noting that I eventually started playing with `react` + `react-native` versions in my `package.json` and now the `react-native` package is not even bundled in my `build` output (which I thought was strange), but it means that I no longer need the workaround. By the way, in case you're curious, here are my [`react` and `react-native`](https://github.com/tatumalenko/MailrKt/blob/main/package.json#L17-L18) versions used.